# Can a Gadgeteer device record and then send its location?

Tags: sockets, geolocation, embedded, coordinates, .net-gadgeteer

Is it possible to imbue (via C# code) location self-awareness into a small piece of "Gadgeteer" (http://gadgeteer.codeplex.com/) hardware?

IOW, I'm wondering if it's possible to write C# code to download into a widget (embedded device) that will be able to use the Geolocation class (or so) to know its own coordinates and then send a wireless signal (using sockets, for example) to a Windows 8 app running on a tablet.

Comment: For communication the other way (from the Windows 8 tile app to Gadgeteer) Pete Brown has some interesting posts: http://10rem.net/blog/2012/06/23/using-udp-sockets-to-connect-a-windows-8-metro-style-app-to-a-net-micro-framework-device-part-2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use [the GPS module](http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/gps-module-net-gadgeteer-compatible-p-971.html?cPath=203) to glean location (at least outside) and [the Wi-Fi module](http://www.ghielectronics.com/catalog/product/282) (or any of [the connectivity modules](http://www.gadgeteering.net/hardware?type%5B%5D=mainboard&type%5B%5D=module&field_module_type_tid=11&field_hi_manufacturer_nid=All&=Apply)) to facilitate a connection to a server and post the result. The Win8 tile app could then read the Gadgeteer module's location from the same web server.